# timezones with moment Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have this code block where I have scheduledTime and timezone received from API for example
scheduledTime: 1603890000000
timezone: "EDT"

and I would like to display this in the timezone of the device of the user i.e CST. What's the best way around it?

```
 <p className="content mb-0 mt-2" style={{color:"#868686"}}>
    {moment(new Date(workout.scheduledTime)).format("hh:mm A")}{" to "}
    {moment(new Date(workout.scheduledTime)).add(workout.duration, "minutes").format("hh:mm A")}{" "}
 </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toLocale()*` function families to display the date in the correct locale

```js
const theDate = new Date( Date.parse('10/28/2020 4:52:48 PM UTC'));
console.log(theDate.toLocaleString())
console.log(theDate.toLocaleTimeString());
console.log(theDate.toLocaleDateString());
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString